# Best practice for creating models in MVC (CRUD)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

So we have added a new programmer to the team and he has some thoughts on how models should be created within MVC that is different from how we have created models previously.  Lets say for example we have a system in which users submit requests for documents and that there is a page in that systems where users calculate a fee for fulfilling that document request.  This fee creation page would have the abiltiy to type in some data about the fee and also the associated invoice.  Users could add invoice line items and use those to auto calculate a fee total.  In that scenario we would normally  create models like the below.

```
    public class Fee
{
    public virtual Guid RequestID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid FeeID { get; set; }
    public string FeeTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal FeeAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{ 
    // Additional Invoice Data (To, From, etc)
}

public class InvoiceLineItem
{
    public string LineItemTitle { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal PricePerUnit { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }

}
```

Our new programmer believes that this is not a good approach because there are different data needs for different operations.  For instance when you create a fee you will need to know the corresponding request ID.  However when you update a fee you will only need to know the FeeID.  Therefore when he has created his models he has created them in such a fashion as that there are multiple layers of inheritance in an effort to control the data that is updated in the service layer and presented on the view.  His thought is that we should be able to assume that any model passed in for a transaction should have all its data points used and not have to guess on what the data depending on circumstance.

To me this adds a ton of needless complexity to our models and makes it far more difficult to work with them on other modules.  Below is a sample which illustrates this.

```
 /// <summary>
/// This model is used to present data in a read fashion to the end user
/// </summary>
public class FeeViewModel : FeeModel_Create
{
    public string FullRequestNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public List<String> States { get; set; }
    public List<FeeAttachmentEditModel> Attachments { get; set; }
    public List<PaymentViewModel> Payments { get; set; }

}

/// <summary>
/// This model adds a request id to the fee update model because we need to know which request this fee is associated with
/// </summary>
public class FeeModel_Create : FeeModel_Update
{
    public Guid RequestID { get; set; }

}

/// <summary>
/// Represents the parameters required to update a fee
/// </summary>
public class FeeModel_Update
{
    public virtual Guid FeeID { get; set; }
    public decimal FeeAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public string FeeTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public List<MaterialList> MaterialTypes { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceLineItem_Adhoc> LineItems { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }


    public void InjectValuesIntoInvoiceModel(Invoice Invoice)
    {
        Invoice.Description = this.Invoice.Description;
        Invoice.Terms = this.Invoice.Terms;
        Invoice.To_Name = this.Invoice.To_Name;
        Invoice.To_Address = this.Invoice.To_Address;
        Invoice.To_Address2 = this.Invoice.To_Address2;
        Invoice.To_City = this.Invoice.To_City;
        Invoice.To_State = this.Invoice.To_State;
        Invoice.To_Zip = this.Invoice.To_Zip;
        Invoice.From_Name = this.Invoice.From_Name;
        Invoice.From_Address = this.Invoice.From_Address;
        Invoice.From_Address2 = this.Invoice.From_Address2;
        Invoice.From_City = this.Invoice.From_City;
        Invoice.From_State = this.Invoice.From_State;
        Invoice.From_Zip = this.Invoice.From_Zip;
    }
}


public class InvoiceLineItem_Adhoc
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
    public InvoiceLineItem ToLineItem(Guid InvoiceID)
    {
        var lineItem = new InvoiceLineItem();
        StaticValueInjecter.InjectFrom(lineItem, this);
        lineItem.InvoiceLineItemID = Guid.NewGuid();
        lineItem.InvoiceID = InvoiceID;
        lineItem.UserID = 1;
        return lineItem;
    }
}

public class PaymentViewModel
{
    public Guid RequestID { get; set; }
    public Guid FeeID { get; set; }
    public string FullRequestNumber { get; set; }
    public string FeeTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid PaymentID { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DatePaid { get; set; }
}

public class FeeAttachmentEditModel
{
    public Guid RequestID { get; set; }
    public Guid FeeID { get; set; }
    public string FullRequestNumber { get; set; }
    public string FeeTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Guid FeeAttachmentID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid AttachmentTypeID { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string mimeType { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentBody { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public bool HadError = false;
}
```

I'm just looking for an answer here on what the best practices for creating models are in MVC.  Should you create separate models whether through inheritance partial classes or other means to accommodate which operation you are conducting creating, reading, updating, or deleting. Or is it better to have one viewmodel that translates to what is presented on/passed from the view and the logic to filter out what is important that's coming from the view model when accessing the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical approach that we take is to have a ViewModel that is tightly coupled to a view and only contains that information. The same goes for InputModels, they should only contain the properties that will be passed in. As for the inheritance piece, I would stay far far away from that approach. Just create simple, flat DTOs and map them from your domain model. There should be no logic so DRY doesn't really apply to this layer of your app.

Comment: Ok, so we have typically only had a view model, so the concept of an input model is kinda new.  Should we have a view model that gets submitted and then translated into an input model via an auto mapper that gets passed back to a service layer?

Comment: The ViewModel is created for when you're rendering the page and the InputModel is used for binding the input in your action. Having separate models allows you to craft a DTO that is exactly what you need for the situation. A ViewModel will typically have more than an InputModel since it will have string values for display and items for dropdowns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

per the first answer, we haven't seen how the viewmodel will be used on a page.  Like he said, the viewmodel should only contain data that will satisfy displaying the view.  you shouldn't just be blindly copying every field from your domain model into the viewmodel.

I also don't like that there's a HasError flag in the view model(s).  Use data annotations or inherit from IValidateableObject to perform validation on your POST's.

I also don't think you need to be injecting values like you are into viewmodel.  if you should be able to projet directly into your viewmodel from a linq query or webservice request.

and the last piece is that for dropdowns on the page, only return the data you need (an Id and description) in a dictionary or some small class so you aren't returning all the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you're dealing with here. "Model" is a loaded term and can mean all sorts of things to all sorts of people.

If the classes, `Fee`, `Invoice`, etc., are entities, which is to say they related directly to a database table, then subclassing them for the purposes of the view, like your developer is doing, is 100% wrong. However, if they are merely view models as well, then there may or may not be merit in subclassing them.

If they are entities, then your developer is right in the sense that you should not be passing the whole entities to/from the view. However, the solution is to create view models, in this case, that contain just the properties necessary for the view. You would then map the data from your entities to/from these view models.

Minor point regarding using AutoMapper for the mapping: you really shouldn't use AutoMapper ever to map *to* an entity. The developer of the library has said as much himself. AutoMapper was never intended to be used to map data back onto an entity, and you'll run into all sorts of idiosyncratic issues with Entity Framework if you do so. These can all be worked around (I've personally done this many times before I knew better), but the amount of code you begin to require and custom things you have to do begin to negate all the benefits of working with AutoMapper in the first place. I'd recommend simply manually mapping the data from your view model back onto your entity.

Answer (score 0):

Your new developer's style is being dictated by the technology (in this case Entity Framework) - which in MHO does not always lend to proper design.

My approach is ...

Models should be logically designed with interfaces - agnostic of how they are used
but will cater to future requirements. 
The inheritance should be kept as shallow as possible without breaking a good
model design.

Views should only interact with the BS via controllers.
Data Services should only interact with Business services. 
Each presentation should have it's own ViewModel which should be as flat as possible.
However a ViewModel may have child ViewModels.

I use DAPPER for in my database services layer and created a code generator that will
generate the DS methods and stored procs. The DS method would only have the relevant
properties to insert/update fields in a DB. 
This makes your code lean, fast and very easy to manage
when you leave the team and someone else has to take over.